# Is it possible to get vertex data from model3D using helixtoolkit?

Tags: c#, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm using *helixtoolkit-3d* to display .obj 3d model and I get the model like that:

```cs
ObjReader CurrentHelixObjReader = new ObjReader();
MyModel = CurrentHelixObjReader.Read("D:/model.obj");
```

I want to get an array of vertex coordinates from model3D which I get like that:

```cs
MyModel.Children[0]
```

I have tried `((GeometryModel3D)MyModel.Children[0]).Bounds`, but it returns Rect3D, but I need to get all vertex coordinates

Comment: I managed to do this:                                                                  `GeometryModel3D gm = ((GeometryModel3D)MyMode.Children[counter]);
                        MeshGeometry3D mg = (MeshGeometry3D)((Geometry3D)gm.Geometry);
                        foreach (var point3D in mg.Positions)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(point3D.X);
                        }`